# File format for generating 3D models from scratch?

Tags: model, 3d, format, export, mesh

I'm beginning a project that will require me to export a user generated 3D model to be used in other programs such as Blender.  For now I am mostly concerned with just the basic mesh data (not animation or bones or textures), though I would like the option to extend it in the future.

My question is this:

What is a good file format to use for 3D models when you will be writing the files from scratch?

My main considerations are:

1. ease of implementation
2. usefulness/universal acceptance (can it handle the information I want, and will most 3D programs recognize the format and be able to import it?)

From my research so far, my thought is to go with COLLADA, but I would appreciate any insights from anyone who has actually played around with the guts of 3D file formats.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the [Wavefront OBJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) format? It's quite simple, widely used, almost any 3D modelling application understands?

Comment: @buc Thanks for the suggestion.  OBJ was another format I was considering, although some stuff I found made it sound kind of outdated.  Also I saw comments suggesting a lot of OBJ loaders are buggy.  But looking at it a little closer, it _does_ look pretty straightforward, especially for my simple application.  I'm curious if anyone who has experience with both OBJ and COLLADA could offer insights and/or recommendations regarding the pros and cons of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research and examining various file formats exported out of blender from the same model, I decided to follow the suggestion made in buc's comment and use the .OBJ format.  It looks to be the easiest, most straightforward format to pick up quickly, and it satisfies everything I would need for my simple application.  If I needed more advanced features though, I would probably go with COLLADA (.dae).

@buc if your comment had been an answer, I would have marked it correct, but either way, I figured it would be good to give this question an official conclusion.